# How can I undo a flag?

Tags: support, flags

Today I wanted to flag a [question which seemed off-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162492/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-mine-doge) while using the Android application, however, my finger slipped and I accidentally hit "Off topic > Game Engine/Development". Also, I noted that the question is actually not about mining a cryptographic currency, but about a cookie clicker clone based on doge (and therefor actually on topic).

That flag wasn't really appropriate for that question, and it got declined. However, is there any way for me to decline my own flags before they get reviewed, so that moderators/reviewers can focus on the important flags, just in case this happens again?

Comment: I propose we request an over-engineered complicated system allowing us to peer review flags, and flag other peoples' flags. We can call it metaflagging. Of course, for flags on Meta, it will have to be called metametaflagging.

Comment: @Wikwocket: What about the peer review? Shouldn't the reviews get reviewed again? After all, who can say that metaflagging isn't error prone? I propose we request metametaflagging. Of course, for metaflags on Meta, it will have to be called metametametaflagging. At the end, it alls ends in the regular questions: who flags the flaggers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't undo your own flags.

And honestly, it's not a huge deal. I mean, it's great that you want to help out, retract the flag yourself, but one little bad flag isn't really all that much of a problem. Especially since the flag wasn't intentional.

Just be careful in the near future (I.E. next week or two), so as not to trip any automated systems that look for multiple bad flags from a user, and you'll be fine.